# Entire function of exponential type $1$ bounded by $1/(1+|x|)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be an entire function of exponential type $1$ such that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{1+|x|}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

- First, I have to show that $|f(z)| \leq \frac{Ce^{|Im(z)|}}{1+|z|} z\in \mathbb{C}$.
- After that, I have to give an example of such a function (not $ 0$) and one more exemple of an entire function of exponential type 1 such that $|f(x)|=O(|x|^{-n}),x\in \mathbb{R},\forall n\geq 1$.

#### Progress

I have proved the first part of my question: We have to study the holomorphic function $g$ defined by $g(z)=f(z)e^{iz}(z+i)^{1/2}$. Now I am trying to find some examples.

Comment: I have proved the first part of my question : We have to study the holomorphic function g defined by : $g(z)=f(z)e^{iz}(z+i)^{1/2}$

Comment: Now i am trying to find some examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did the first part, I do not address it. Concerning the examples,
$c(\sin z)/z$ is the first example that you need. For the second example, take
$\phi(t)$ infinitely differentiable, with support on $(-1,1)$, and consider the
function
$$f(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(t)e^{izt}dt.$$
This is evidently bounded: $|f(x)|\leq \|\phi\|_1$.
Now, 
$$(-iz)^nf(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi^{(n)}(t)e^{izt}dt,$$
(integration by parts), and we obtain that $|f(x)x^n|$ is bounded for all $n$.

Comment: Sorry, i just saw your answer. Please let me try...Thank you. What did you mean by $c(sinz)$ what is the meaning of "c" in your formula ?

Comment: $c$ is a positive constant. I was just lazy to think whether $\sin x/x<1/1+|x|$ or not. So I put a constant just for the case.

Comment: how do you know that they are functions of exponential type 1 ?

Comment: Who "they"? Sine? Evident by definition. Fourier transform of $\phi$? Straightforward estimate of $|f(z)|$.