# Real part of entire function of exponential type $1$ bounded by $1/(1+|x|)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove the first part of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207459/entire-function-of-exponential-type-1-bounded-by-1-1x), but I could not do it.

It says:

> Let $f$ be an entire function of exponential type $1$ (i.e., there exist a constant $A$ such that $|f(z)| < Ae^{|z|}$), and suppose that $|f(x)| \leq \frac{1}{1+|x|}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $|f(z)| \leq \frac{Ce^{|\Im(z)|}}{1+|z|}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ (I guess that $C$ is a complex constant).

The author of that post said that we had to study the function $g(z) = f(z)e^{iz}(z+i)^{1/2}$. However, I don't know why it is important to use that function. Can you explain to me how to use this hint or how I can solve the problem in another way?

Comment: because in the upper half plane $g$ is bounded since first $|f(x+iy)| \le Ke^{|y|}$ because $f$ bounded on the real axis (and exponential type $1$) and then $|g(z)| \le K_1$; this gives the result there and similarly you can use $g_1(z) = f(z)e^{-iz}(z-i)^{1/2}$ on the lower half plane

Comment: @Conrad I know that $|f(z)| < Ke^{|z|}$ because $f$ is of exponential type $1$. Why does the boundness of $f$ in the real axis imply that $|f(z)| < Ke^{|y|}$?

Comment: @Conrad Furthermore, why are we using $(z+i)^{1/2}$? Assume that $|g(z)|\leq K_1$ in the upper half plane. Since $|g(z)| = \frac{|f(z)|\sqrt{|z+i|}}{e^{|\Im(z)|}}$, we have that $|f(z)|\leq \frac{K_1e^{|\Im(z)|}}{\sqrt{|z+i|}}$. However, we can't conclude that the last term is less or equal than $\frac{K_1e^{|\Im(z)|}}{1+|z|}$ because we don't have that $\sqrt{|z+i|}\leq 1+|z|$. Actually, for $z=i$ the last inequality does not hold.

Comment: that's a general result that follows from Phragmen Lindelof (see for example Boas, Entire Functions, Thm 6.2.3 - you can apply Phragmen Lindelof directly to $g$ btw with a little care); actually you are right one needs to use $z+i$ here since the original bound is $1/(1+|x|)$ - if the original bound is $1/(1+|x|)^{1/2}$ then one uses that - more generally if you have a bound $\omega(x)$ and you have a holomorphic function that is not large and is bounded by $1/\omega(x)$ on the real axis, same proof works; Boas discusses this also in chapter 6, page 89

Comment: @Conrad I didn't know about that theorem. Is that the only theorem that I need to solve the problem?

Comment: Phragmen Lindelof is essentially what you need and is a must when you study entire functions (there are various versions, but all are generalizations of maximum modulus to unbounded domains, where you know apriori that the original function is not too large)

Comment: @Conrad Thanks a lot! I have to study a little deeper exponential type functions because I am doing a project about them. Can you suggest me some bibliography to learn about the basic properties of those functions? I know only basic complex analysis, as the one that is taught in an undergraduate course.

Comment: Levin (Lectures on Entire Functions) or Boas (Entire Functions) are the references I use when needing stuff about exponential-type functions; they are similar in what they cover, but Boas has stuff organized in topics, while Levin is like a class that develops the material from more or less first principles (eg Jensen etc), so for studying Levin is more suited imho, while for a fast check about results you need for something else, Boas is better

Comment: @Conrad Do you think it is possible to prove some of the most important properties of exponential type functions without Phragmen-Lindelöf Theorem? For instance, see this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699693/without-phragm%c3%a9n-lindel%c3%b6f-f-is-of-exponential-type-and-bounded-on-the-real-a

Comment: That's how you prove phragmen lindelof essentially so of course you can do it just for this case; the idea is to take large rectangles (one side on the real axis and then going up (towards $i\infty$) and left right towards $\pm \infty$) and show that a modified function is bounded by what you want; similarly for the lower half plane with a different modification